# Breadcrumb is not generating the correct post page url

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-development, themes, breadcrumb

I have created a custom posts type cities and the code for its deceleration is `register_post_type('City',$args);`

```
  $labels = array(
'name' => _x('Cities', 'post type general name'),
'singular_name' => _x('City', 'post type singular name'),
......  );
```

and I Installed prime-strategy-bread-crumb to generate the breadcrumbs but the exact url for cities page is http://www.abc.com/wordpress/cities/ and the url generated by the breadcrumb is http://www.acb.com/wordpress/city/ which ultimately takes me to the archive page of post type city so do I have to make changes in the plugin file or is it all due to page url because the url of single city post is //www.abc.com/wordpress/city/shimla/ and code to display the breadcrumbs is in this page.

Comment: http://www.abc.com/wordpress/city/ is correct, Labels does not matter to the urls/slug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Labels are for the use in the Adminsection of your Website.

If you want to change the slug in the URL of your CPT, use this values in your `register_post_type` function call.

```
$rewrite = array(
    'slug' => __( 'cities', 'your_textdomain' ),
    //......
)

$args = array(
    'rewrite' => $rewrite,
    //......
);
```

Comment: Thanks Fischi, it worked but it also change the permalink to my single post http://www.abc.com/wordpress/city/shimla/ in to http://www.abc.com/wordpress/cities/shimla/ and when I click on cities to it again takes me to cities archive page

Comment: Oh ok, I see. In this case, the better solution would be to create a redirect from the `http://www.acb.com/wordpress/city/` page to the `http://www.acb.com/wordpress/cities/`. Then you got both flies with one clap.

Comment: ok I am creating a wordpress theme so tell me how to redirect it

Comment: sorry fischi I wnat to re correct my comment your solution worked till the time I don't updated my permalinks but when I updated me permalink structure to /%category%/%postname%/ both the breadcrumb link and navigation link get converted to  http://www.acb.com/wordpress/cities/ and again displaying the archive page of city post type

Comment: hae I found something similar to my problem [Breadcrumbs with Custom Post Types?](http://www.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2349/breadcrumbs-with-custom-post-types)

Comment: [Breadcrumb NavXT](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/breadcrumb-navxt/) really rocks fixed my problem